# vue-server-renderer – invalid expression when trying to interpolate template e.g. with title or meta data

Tags: node.js, vue.js, server-side-rendering

When I try to compile the following server-side code with

vue 2.5.13
node 9.9.0

I get an "unexpected token" error. I don't know why that is. I am simply trying to do an extrapolation. Unfortunately I can not codepen, because this is server side code. But the example is bare bones, so it should be possible to reproduce.

Here's the code:

```
const Vue = require('vue');
const renderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createRenderer();

let template = `<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  {{{meta}}}
  <title>{{{title}}}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--vue-ssr-outlet-->
</body>
</html>`;

let app = new Vue({
  data: {
    meta: '<meta/>',
    title: 'title'
  },
  template: template
}); 

renderer.renderToString(app, (err, html) => {

  if (err) {
    console.error(err);  
  }

  console.log(html);

});
```

This is the error I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  {{{meta}}}
  <title>{{{title}}}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--vue-ssr-outlet-->
</body>
</html>
- invalid expression: Unexpected token ) in

    "\n  "+_s({meta)+"}\n  "

  Raw expression: {{{meta}}}

- invalid expression: Unexpected token ) in

    _s({title)+"}"

  Raw expression: {{{title}}}



(found in <Root>)

at onCompilationError (/path/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7378:9)
at compileToFunctions (/path/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:5536:9)
at normalizeRender (/path/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7388:22)
at render (/path/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:7752:5)
at Object.renderToString (/path/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.js:8232:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/path/playground/vue-render.js:24:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the section on [Template Interpolation](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/basic.html#using-a-page-template) in SSR guide.  I think `{{{title}}}` in your code ought to be `{{title}}` (two instead of three curly brackets) since its just a string and not HTML.

The forward slash in `<meta/>` probably needs to be escaped.